# Featured image for teasers?

Tags: media, nodes

I have a client who is an architect. I've created a content type called "project" that allows them to select multiple images to display on a page. These project items get promoted to the home page as teasers, however I'd like the customer to be able to select a featured image to display in the teaser, rather than having every image display.

Anyone know an easy way of doing this without having multiple image fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be with some code in custom module, 
first image is featured

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_view_alter().
 */
function HOOK_node_view_alter(&$build) {  
  if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'teaser' && isset($build['field_image'][1])) {
    foreach ($build['field_image'] AS $k => $item) {
      if (is_numeric($k) && $k > 0) {
        unset($build['field_image'][$k]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

change "field_image" to your field_name

Comment: This doesn't create a featured image, this _removes_ all other images, which potentially creates problems down the road. It's not sustainable solutions.

Comment: the process is in theme layer and not make anything persistent with real data, so I think this solution is OK. Please, explain situation with possible problems follow this solution, thank you. BTW I search for solution to make Image Widget were to set this per content type and display view, with no success in this time

Comment: The fundamental problem is that you are assuming that nothing else further down the line has no need for the data you are unseting, which is, in my personal opinion, a total hack.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way is to make the *first* image also be the "featured" one, as then you already have most of the functionality built in.

It is then trivial to use a view that filters on "Image field: delta = 1", to give you only that one image, and then output it where appropriate.

A php savvy themer could also pull out the first image right in the template as well.